# Using apache beam JsonTimePartitioning to create time partitioned tables in bigqiery

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

I have tried using the JsonTimePartitioning class in apache beam JAVA sdk to write data to dynamic tables in bigquery but i get "cannot find symbol" for the class JsonTimePartitioning.

**this is how i try to import the class**

```java
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JsonTimePartitioning;
```

**and this is how i try to use it in my pipeline**

```java
  .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
  .withJsonTimePartitioningTo(new JsonTimePartitioning().setType("DAY")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find the `JsonTimePartitioning` anywhere. Can you point to an example that you are trying to follow? The existing methods on `BigQueryIO` either accept an instance of [`TimePartiotioning`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withTimePartitioning-com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TimePartitioning-), or a [value-provider for a `String`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withJsonTimePartitioning-org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider-) that is actually a JSON-serialized instance of the same `TimePartitioning`. And in fact, when calling the `TimePartitioning` version of the method, you still end up just [serializing it into string internally:](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c2f0d282337f3ae0196a7717712396a5a41fdde1/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L1806). You can find an example of how it's used [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html):

> Loading historical data into time-partitioned BigQuery tables To load
>   historical data into a time-partitioned BigQuery table, specify
>   `BigQueryIO.Write.withTimePartitioning(com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TimePartitioning)`
>   with a field used for column-based partitioning. For example:
>
> ````java
>  PCollection<Quote> quotes = ...;
>
>  quotes.apply(BigQueryIO.write()
>          .withSchema(schema)
>          .withFormatFunction(quote -> new TableRow()
>             .set("timestamp", quote.getTimestamp())
>             .set(..other columns..))
>          .to("my-project:my_dataset.my_table")
>          .withTimePartitioning(new TimePartitioning().setField("time"))); ```
> ````

Comment: Hi Anton, I tried using your solution but i guess this doesnt work for dynamic destinations. i solved it by adding the tablepartitioning parameter to TableDestination isnstead of using BigQueryIO.Write as follows
`TableDestination(destination, null, new TimePartitioning().setField("CheckInDate"))`